# how to make this jtable scrollable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

When I try to put a vertical scrollpane in the table, the table ctab just disappears. here is the code:

```
    ctab = new JTable();
    ctab.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);



    ctab.setBounds(15, 97, 780, 347);
    frmKusinaNiKambal.getContentPane().add(ctab);
            ctab.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][] {
                    {"", "", null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                },
                new String[] {
                    "Contract #", "Engager", "Contact #", "Client Address", "Date", "Time", "Event Address", "Contract FilePath", "Referred By"
                }
            ) {
                boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
                    false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false
                };
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return columnEditables[column];
                }
            });
            ctab.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(102);
            ctab.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(62);
            ctab.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(41);
            ctab.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(95);
            ctab.isEnabled();
```

How can i get this table to be scrollable?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see in your posted code where you deal anywhere with a JScrollPane. Rather your code shows you placing the JTable directly into the contentPane.

The solution is to

- place the JTable into a JScrollPane's viewport. You can do this by passing the JTable into the JScrollPane's constructor, or by calling `setViewportView(...)` on the JScrollPane and passing in the JTable.
- Then place the JScrollPane, not the JTable, into your GUI.
- Learn about and use the Swing layout managers. Absolute positioning with null layouts and setBounds will lead you to rigid difficult to upgrade GUIs.

---

Useful Tutorial Links:

- [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)
- [JScrollPane Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- [Layout Manager Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [JTable Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: so I declare the Jscrollpane first before the JTable?

Comment: @user3209957: no, the order of declaration has nothing to do with this. If you haven't read the JScrollPane tutorial, please do so soon.

Comment: @user3209957: tutorial links added to answer.